# How do I run LibreOffice Calc without Text Input dialog?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, automation

I have a CSV file written by a python script of mine.  I want to make a shell script that opens the file in read-only mode, which I have done.

```
#!/bin/sh
libreoffice --view ~/Documents/timeclock.csv
```

My problem is that every time I open it, the Text Input dialog opens.  This is an example of what the file looks like.  It's semicolon separated.  How can I get libreoffice to either use pre-set settings, or command line arguments?

```
;;;;;=SUM(D2:D100)
;;;;;15
;;;;;=F1*F2

=DATE(2012,10,13);=TIME(10,21,56);=TIME(18,45,27);=ABS(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) - INDIRECT("C" & ROW()))*24
=DATE(2012,10,21);=TIME(10,23,16);=TIME(17,17,12);=ABS(INDIRECT("B" & ROW()) - INDIRECT("C" & ROW()))*24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:
http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Handling_Spreadsheet_Documents_Files

and:

http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options

with UNO you can set the filter options. With that you can write e.g. a StarBasic macro.  http://www.openoffice.org/api/basic/man/tutorial/tutorial.pdf helps you with that.

You should be able to run such a macro from the commandline: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8232

Another alternative is using Python/PyUno, Java or C++.